# Filling a html form using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Hey all I am trying to fill a html form using a java program but i stuck half way. actually i am able to fetch the page but can't write it back to server or possibly able to write it back but with no response from server.

Here is my Program:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class fillForm{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Socket s = null;
        try{
            s = new Socket("localhost", 80);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            /******************
              Now download the page from the server.
             ******************/
            bw.write("GET /phpsandbox/form.html HTTP/1.1\n");
            bw.write("Host: localhost:80\n\n");
            bw.flush();
            readResponse(br);
            //now i have read whole input now its time to write output.
            bw.write("GET /phpsandbox/form.php?uName=hello HTTP/1.1\n");
            bw.write("Host: localhost:80\n\n");
            bw.flush();
            readResponse(br);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }                   
    }
    public static void readResponse(BufferedReader br){
        String newLine;
        try{
            while((newLine = br.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println("Line: " + newLine);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

nd here is form.html

```
<html>
<head><title>form</title></head>
<body>
<form action="form.php" method="GET">
<label>Enter name</label>
<input name="uName"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is form.php residing in same folder as the form.html

```
<?php
        //read the response from the client
        echo "hELLO";
        echo $_GET['uName'];
?>
```

And here is the output:

```
Line: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Line: Date: Sun, 06 Feb 2011 13:46:17 GMT
Line: Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8k PHP/5.2.9 mod_apreq2-20051231/2.6.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
Line: Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Feb 2011 13:29:58 GMT
Line: ETag: "6c3c-b5-49b9d1c8f56c1"
Line: Accept-Ranges: bytes
Line: Content-Length: 181
Line: Content-Type: text/html
Line: 
Line: <html>
Line: <head><title>form</title></head>
Line: <body>
Line: <form action="form.php" method="GET">
Line: <label>Enter name</label>
Line: <input name="uName"/>
Line: <input type="submit" />
Line: </form>
Line: </body>
Line: </html>
```

After giving the output program waits for sometime then exits.

Thanks:)

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why do not you write simple HTTP servlet?

Comment: Have you considered using a more appropriate library, such as the Apache HTTPComponents? http://hc.apache.org/

Comment: @AlexR: How to do with HTTP Servlet?

Comment: @Tom: I'll try this but can u tell me how to do with sockets??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on HTTP protocol; take a look here for instance: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html. I think it wants a couple of blank lines between the first GET and the second one.

If that fails, close the socket and open a new one, that should work.